# Exporting ios .ipa file without developer account in flutter

Tags: xcode, flutter

A youtube video: https://youtu.be/kBnUB48wf2w

I try to export the app to a .ipa file without developer account. But when I try to "Archive" it in xcode. It run into an error.

`"Runner" requires a provisioning profile. Enable development signing and select a provisioning profile in the project editor.`

I have already select the signing to "Ad Hoc Code Sign". But it seems to be still not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can only run your project on a device with non-developer account. If you referred to this:

[Choosing a Membership](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)

It states that:

> You can learn how to develop apps for Apple platforms for free without enrolling. With just an Apple ID, you can access Xcode, software downloads, documentation, sample code, forums, and bug reporter, and you can test your apps on devices.

The archiving process means that you are preparing your project to be distributed either on ad-hoc or by uploading it directly to the app store.